# How to change in word PHP?

Tags: php

```
<?php

    $var1 = $_POST['var1'];
    $var2 = $_POST['var1'];

    echo $var1 + var2;
?>
```

> OUTPUT

value1value2

how can i change 'value' text to 'data' text?

Comment: Can you please describe your Question? You have created two variable and you are getting same value in both? is both value will be numeric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str_replace` it's `php` function

```
<?php

$var1 = $_POST['val1'];

echo str_replace("value","data", $var1);

?>
```

Comment: @DarshanaRaval .. If it works accept the answer so that other SO user will get benefit too